Force docker build to not verify TLS certs (WSL)
Running docker in WSL2 ubuntu image.
I want to disable TLS verification for my docker build for testing purposes.
How can I accomplish this? I tried the following:

Adjust /etc/docker/dameon.json, however putting any settings in here does not seem to be recognized.
Adjusted /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf and added Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry registry-1.docker.io
Tried adding --tlsverify=false to my command.

None of this worked. How can I accomplish this.
Note: Please do not comment about how this is insecure and should not be done. I already understand the implications of doing this, its for testing in a close in env, this is not production stuff. Also please dont post about how I can use openssl to gather the cert and add it to my cert store. That is not the point of my question, I am already aware this can be accomplished.
